# Swift: Twilio send SMS, A \'To\' phone number is required

Tags: swift, twilio

Hello im trying to send an SMS text through swift using Twilio. Here is the function below. I left out my account info for obvious reasons.

```
    func sendMessage(Message: String, PhoneNumber: String) -> Int
    {
        let accountSID: String =
        let authToken: String =
        let url = "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/\(accountSID)/Messages"
            
        let parameters = ["From": "+12155154741", "To": "+15712696239", "Body": Message]
            
        AF.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).authenticate(username: accountSID, password: authToken).responseString {response in debugPrint(response)}
            
        return 1
    }
```

The error I get is "A 'To' phone number is required." I've tried the numbers with without the +1. Im confused, am I missing something simple here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use url encode for the parameters and not JSON.
As suggested in the Twilio docs
https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/send-messages
See the CURL example.
Im not sure you need the auth part as well.

Or take a look here - https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/11/how-to-send-an-sms-from-ios-in-swift.html

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and the correct answer I really appreciate it!

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist here. Can I recommend that you follow the advice in the linked blog post and not embed or use your Twilio Account SID and Auth Token within an iOS application as it is a potential security issue.

Comment: Url encoding worked for me as well!